# Faster alternative than a loop to create a numpy array

Tags: numpy

I have an array which contains point clouds (about 100 ladar points). I need to create a set of numpy arrays as quickly as possible.

```
sweep = np.empty(
    shape=(len(sweep.points),),
    dtype=[
        ('point', np.float64, 3),
        ('intensity', np.float32),
        ## ..... more fields ....
    ]
)

for index, point in enumerate(sweep.points):
        sweep[index]['point'] = (point.x, point.y, point.z)
        sweep[index]['intensity'] = point.intensity
        ## ....more fields...
```

Writing an explicit loop is very inefficient and slow. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I'm inferring that `sweep` is a list of `points` objects, where each `point` has attributes that you want to place fields of the array, right?  Wait this won't work.  After defining the `empty` array, `sweep` is now an array, not the list of objects!

Answer (score 2):

It's slightly faster to use a list comprehension to format the data and pass it directly to a numpy array:

```
np.array([((point.x, point.y, point.z), point.intensity)
          for point in points],
         dtype=[('point', np.float64, 3),
                ('intensity', np.float32)])
```

Comment: [np.fromiter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) might be 5% faster still or so if that would matter. All it takes to change the code is to change np.array to np.fromiter, change the list comprehension to a generator expression, and add the argument count=len(points).

Comment: Actually, Is there a parallel way to doing this? (Obviously without me explictly writing parallel code)